# Using Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp to Load Images from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, storage, cross-origin-embedder-policy

To use `SharedArrayBuffer` on Chrome, Firefox, and other browsers, I've followed the instructions in this [Mozilla document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer), it mentions that setting `require-corp` on the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy` header is necessary because `credentialless` doesn't work for Firefox.

But after using `require-corp`, I was not able to load any image from Firebase Storage because of this error:

```
net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 200
```

I'm working with Vue.js and have attempted to configure CORS using the following settings:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
  ]
```

I'm looking for a way to make it work with both `SharedArrayBuffer` and allow images to be loaded from Firebase Storage without having to add `crossorigin="anonymous"` to any `<img>` tag.

Here is [an example image](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rodeotestenv.appspot.com/o/videos%2F0B18AFE5-74F3-4489-AD3E-99007C073E56%2F0B18AFE5-74F3-4489-AD3E-99007C073E56.png?alt=media&token=7f04acc1-a586-4b66-bc5c-4c63115300cf&_gl=1*iqwptq*_ga*MTU3NzI3NTE0Ni4xNjk2MjY2NDAw*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY5NjUxNDM2OC4xMy4xLjE2OTY1MjI1MDIuNDkuMC4w)

Here is my headers:

```
'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy': 'cross-origin'
```